# Update column if has_many field exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two tables `business_hours` and `working_hours`.

The models:

```
class BusinessHour < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :working_hours, class_name: "WorkingHour"
  belongs_to :organization
  accepts_nested_attributes_for(:working_hours, update_only: true)
end


class WorkingHour < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :business_hour

  validates :day, inclusion: { in: %w(mon tue wed thu fri sat sun) }

  validate :validate_day, on: :create

  def validate_day
    if business_hour.working_hours.where(day: self.day).exists?
      errors.add(:day, "has already been added")
    end
  end
end
```

The controller:

```
class Api::V1::Admin::BusinessHoursController < Api::BaseController 
  def update
    @organization.build_business_hours unless @organization.business_hours
    if @organization.business_hours.update(business_hour_params)
      render status: :ok,
        json: { notice: I18n.t("resource.update", resource_name: "Organization") }
    else
      render status: :unprocessable_entity, json: { errors: @organization.business_hours.errors.full_messages }
    end
  end

  private

    def business_hour_params
      params.require(:business_hours).permit(
        :enabled, :away_message, working_hours_attributes: [:day, :start_time, :end_time]
      )
    end
end
```

When the `business_hours` is updated , I'm trying to update the `working_hours` as well.

The required behaviour is that, the `working_hours` should be created with day field from `mon` to `friday` and each `business_hour` will have 7 `working_hours` entry. For example, if a `working_hour` with day as "mon" already exists for a `business_hour`, when the update method in controller is called , only the `start_time` and `end_time` needs to be updated for the particular `working_hour`. How to go about this?

Request body example:

```
{
    "business_hours": {
        "enabled": true,
        "away_message": "Hello",
        "working_hours_attributes": [{
            "day": "mon",
            "start_time": "Tue, 06 Sep 2022 10:07:21.771116000 UTC +00:00",
            "end_time": "Tue, 06 Sep 2022 10:07:21.771116000 UTC +00:00"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, nested attributes can be updated by using "id" key, if your frontend doesn't have this info you could treat the parameters to convert `day: 'mon'` to `id: id` by storing your 'working_hours' into a key-value pair, be careful to not set 'id' as nil so you won´t create new instances (if desired), I don´t think there is a better way of doing it without using this middleware between your update and your permitted parameters

Comment: @saviu-u Can you please post this as an answer with the required changes for those who are new to rails please?

Comment: @saviu-u Each business hour has 7 working hours. There are business_hours for each organization.

Comment: First things first, are you intending to update all "working_hours" (from a specific week day) from all "business_hours" available to that organization?, I assume your "business_hours" is a "has_many" relationship from your organization and I saw you treated "business_hours" sending a ".errors" as if it is an ApplicationRecord, can you clarify this behaviour? is the update meant to update one "business_hour" or multiple "business_hours" that matched the same week day?

Comment: @saviu-u There is only one business_hour for each organization (has_one) . Each business hour is supposed to have 7 working_hours from day mon to sun. When we send a working_hour obj in json with day as mon, if day monday already exists for the business hour, I need to update only start_time and end_time of that particular business hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### As said on the comment:

> Well, nested attributes can be updated by using "id" key, if your frontend doesn't have this info you could treat the parameters to convert `day: 'mon'` to `id: id` by storing your 'working_hours' into a key-value pair, ..., I don´t think there is a better way of doing it without using this middleware between your update and your permitted parameters

```rb
class Api::V1::Admin::BusinessHoursController < Api::BaseController 
  def update
    @organization.build_business_hours unless @organization.business_hours
    if @organization.business_hours.update(update_business_hour_params)
      render status: :ok,
        json: { notice: I18n.t("resource.update", resource_name: "Organization") }
    else
      render status: :unprocessable_entity, json: { errors: @organization.business_hours.errors.full_messages }
    end
  end

  private

  def business_hour_params
    params.require(:business_hours).permit(
      :enabled, :away_message, working_hours_attributes: [:day, :start_time, :end_time]
    )
  end

  # THIS HASN'T BEEN TESTED, USE IT AS AN EXAMPLE
  def update_business_hour_params
    update_business_hour_params = business_hour_params
    update_business_hour_params[:working_hours_attributes].each do |working_hour_parameters|
      working_hour_parameters[:id] = working_hours_day_id_pair[working_hour_parameters.delete(:day)] # Retrieves the id from the day
    end

    update_business_hour_params
  end

  def working_hours_day_id_pair
    @working_hours_day_id_pair ||= @organization.business_hours.working_hours.pluck(:day, :id).to_h
  end
end
```

as said, this is an example, I could not test the code, but that's the idea

as your attributes is already update_only, you should be good to go, hope this helps you

Comment: quick tip: There are prettier ways to handle errors on controllers natively, check [rescue_from](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from), you can use it for 'unprocessable_entity' errors

Comment: @savio-u I have a few more doubts, would't using delete(:day) delete the day key. I want to create or update the working_hour. When we create a business hour for first time, the working_hours does not exist.In this case we have to create new one also. For example , if the day "mon" in working_hours array does not exist for the business_hour, we have to create it first.

Comment: then you can just use '[]' instead of delete, I see you set 'update_only' as 'true', that would need to change as well, then, empty days would return 'nil' as id, which rails understands as a new instance

Comment: "PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column \"business_hour_id\" of relation \"working_hours\" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (78c294ff-e667-420e-b37d-ce42400d15b9, mon, 2022-09-06 10:07:21.771116, 2022-09-06 10:07:21.771116, null).\n" . I'm getting this error when I try to create a second working_hour

Comment: I think that is a rails behaviour (or bug, idk) that you can solve by removing `class_name: 'WorkingHour'` from your `has_many :working_hours`, rails should  still interpret 'working_hours' as that model, so it was redundant anyway and might solve your issue, let me know if it does

Comment: Can you please mark as solved? I'll appreciate it, thanks!